# MongoDB - too many connections w/ node.js

Tags: mongodb, node.js

I'm using node.js and MongoDB for my application. Whenever I use localhost, I have no problems and the application works fine. However, on the server, the database is limiting me to 50 connections. Here's an example of the log:

```
Wed Jul 27 13:33:29 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
Wed Jul 27 13:33:29 [websvr] web admin interface listening on port 28017
Wed Jul 27 13:34:50 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:42035 #1
Wed Jul 27 13:35:16 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:42181 #2
Wed Jul 27 13:35:16 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:42182 #3
Wed Jul 27 13:35:25 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:42249 #4
...
Wed Jul 27 13:36:09 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:42518 #50
Wed Jul 27 13:36:10 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:42524 #51
Wed Jul 27 13:36:10 [initandlisten] can't create new thread, closing connection
```

I'm launching the process with the command `mongod --maxConns=5000`. Does anyone know what could be causing this connection limit?

Comment: Did you get a solution to this?

Comment: https://medium.com/@kyle_martin/mongodb-in-production-how-connection-pool-size-can-bottleneck-application-scale-439c6e5a8424

Answer (score 3):

Can you post the code you're using to connect?  If you're connecting to the DB on each request then you'll quickly run out of connections.  In most cases it's best to share the DB connection among requests, for example by connecting on app startup.